# How to award the bounty after the time expires?

Tags: discussion, support, bounty

I somehow missed the last date of bounty. Can the moderators now help me to reward the remaining bounty on this question now?

[Do side sleeping postures contribute to breast sagging?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/9621/do-side-sleeping-postures-contribute-to-breast-sagging)

Answer (score 5):

Moderators do not have this capability. That said, the bounty seems to have been automatically awarded, no?

Comment: The bounty was of 100 points. Only 50 have been awarded automatically.

Comment: @AnishaKaul Did you get the email notification?  I believe the system sends a reminder when a bounty is about to expire.

Answer (score 3):

The bounty was automatically awarded, that means that only half the bounty award is awarded to the user.

There's nothing we moderators can do about that, we can refund bounties while they're still running under exceptional circumstances, but we can't do anything once a bounty is awarded.